# Can a real-time process exist in the 'expired' queue of linux kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, scheduling

**In the Linux kernel 2.4:**

Real-time processes are given a priority of 0-99 and they co-exist in the ready queue along with the nice processes (who's priority goes between 100 and 139). But real-time processes are supposed to run as long as they need to, so when their time-slice is consumed, they get more time.

**So can the real-time process exist in the expired queue where all processes who consumed their time-slice are present?**

Answer (score 0):

`real-time process` in case of hard real-time, that are processes that never expire. So it is obviously that they can't exist in expired queue. However kernel 2.4 does not guarantee real-time capabilities, so you need an patched kernel. For soft real-time it is possible.